# How to turn off the Windows Defender notification-icon in Windows OS Build 10.0.15063?

Tags: windows-10, notifications, notification-area, windows-defender, windows-10-v1703

Tried the group policy, tried the direct registry setting, tried the notification-settings - nothing works anymore. Does anyone know the magic trick to turn off the Windows Defender notification-icon?

The icon I am speaking off:

[image: Persistent Windows Defender icon]

Comment: Although we still haven't found an answer yet, this question has been asked before:  [Windows 10 Creator Update - Ignore specific “performance & health” recommendations?](https://superuser.com/q/1195303/650163).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to turn off Windows Defender permanently](https://superuser.com/questions/950744/how-to-turn-off-windows-defender-permanently)

Comment: Install a different anti-malware suite, e.g. Avira, Avast... That will remove the icon. Don't operate without protection.

Answer (score -1):

Just head over to the taskmanager -> Autostart -> deactivate "Windows Defender notification icon"